# Is there any way to hide a password on github?

Tags: git, github, server, passwords

I'm looking for a solution about a little probleme : I forked a git repository from [rAthena](https://github.com/rathena/rathena), and there is a common password for db in a file.

I changed this password, added the file in .git/info/exclude in local and in .gitignore in my fork and removed the file from git. But once I triied to pull from the master rAthena into my fork to update the changes, and now it says that a file is missing (the one with the password), and everytime i try to commit/push my local changes it say the same thing. Is there another way to do ? Or may i miss something ?

[the error itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ykN.png)

Basically i don't want to see my password online, every solution for this might be great, but i don't want to change the file everytime i pull the git on my server.

Pagalom

Comment: There's no way around it, the secret has to come from outside your repo. Each time you do a new clone, you'll have to bring in the secret from somewhere else safe. If you have a sandbox that you reuse, however, you should be able to put the secret in just once, when you clone, and not have to refresh it every time you pull. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: @joanis that happened until now, and since i triied to pull from the far repository (rAthena itself) the error appears, for now i forced the push and delete the file from my commit, and it's working, but i'm afraid that next update will make an error again, i'm not confident about my actions ... I'll up-to-date this post if something like this appears again. Thanks for your advise.

Moreover, I was wondering if a little script on my server who modify the secret when we pull might be a good idea ? Do you know ?